# Интерпретатор Python не верно вычисляет

Tags: python

print ((3.14+0.3)/2+0.15) = 1.8666666669
А если вручную пересчитать, то получается 1.87

Comment: Все он верно вычисляет, округлите до двух знаков после запятой и выйдет ваш ответ

Comment: Типичная проблема потери точности при операциях с float. Используйте Decimal

Comment: А почему при ручном расчете получается так, а в интерпретаторе получается такое большое число? Это понятно что можно округлить, но вот не знаю с чем это связано(

Comment: Связано это с тем что float в двоичном представлении не может быть представлен точно, всегда есть погрешность. И поэтому 1.1 + 2.2 = 3.3000000000000003

Comment: Используйте `round`: `n = (3.14+0.3)/2+0.15` `print(n)` `print(round(n, 2))`

Comment: И никого из комментаторов  не смутила такая гигантская погрешность? Я вот не поверил, посмотрел сам, получил 1.8699999999999999. Вот это куда больше похоже на правду.